# how to write a postgresql query to fetch field value inside array of json data

Tags: postgresql

The following data is a sample json data in postgres db

```
    {
        "RA1":{
            "RaItems": [
                {
                    "a": 1,
                    "b": 2
                },
                {
                    "a": 11,
                    "b": 22
                },
                {
                    "a": 111,
                    "b": 222
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

I tried my query to fetch only a's field values in my select clause:
select data->'RA1'->RaItems'->0->'a' from table;

but i need a postgressql query to fetch all a's inspite of dynamic array length like a output below:
1,11,111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use the `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS` function and then wrap the whole thing in an outer query

```
SELECT d->'a' FROM (
   SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS (bada->'RA1'->'RaItems') AS d FROM mytable
) AS subq
```